# Alignment issue after adding overflow-x in HTML css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display some data in table in MVC.When text content is greater than cell size of the table i want a scroll bar to appear on bottom of cell. so far I am able to make scroll bar appear however the scroll bar goes beyond boundaries of the particular cell.**Code is Smoothly running on chrome issue is with internet explorer**

[image]

how can i get this scroll bar inside a particular cell?

my code is as follow:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
white-space: normal;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
max-width: 280px;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.topright {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*overflow-x: scroll;*/
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.td-scroll {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something1</th>
      <th>Something2</th>
      <th>Something3</th>
      <th>Something4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>blabla</td>
    <td>bla bla bla</td>
    <td class="td-scroll">this text should be have scroll bar to view entire text</td>
    <td>bla bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: scroll appears for me if there is enough text https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XROQZM

Comment: @MichaelCoker scroll appears for me when i tried it on jsfiddle as well but facing issue when i am trying same thing in my MVC webpage.(Note:I am using Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: are there other styles that are overwriting that behavior?

Comment: @MichaelCoker please check image i have attached for reference.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i added my entire css code block